# Compare two multidimensional arrays and output result in a new array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 6423 
            [gdat] => 2019-02-06 
        ) 
    [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 9700
            [gdat] => 2019-02-07 
        ) 
    [2] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 12559
            [gdat] => 2019-02-08 
        )
)

Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 6423 
            [gdat] => 2019-02-06 
        ) 
    [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 9604 
            [gdat] => 2019-02-07 
        ) 
    [2] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 11559 
            [gdat] => 2019-02-08 
        )
)
```

The values for `[passers]` in the first array will be always bigger than those in the second one, for `[gdat]` always the same in both arays.

I need to compare the values of two `[passers]` and output the result in a new array:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 0
            [gdat] => 2019-02-06 
        ) 
    [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 96
            [gdat] => 2019-02-07 
        ) 
    [2] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 1000
            [gdat] => 2019-02-08 
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a one-to-one correspondence as you show in your question, you can just loop over array1 and subtract the values from array2:

```
$array3 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $array3[$key]['passers'] = $value['passers'] - $array2[$key]['passers'];
    $array3[$key]['gdat'] = $value['gdat'];
}
```

If the keys in array2 don't necessarily correspond to those in array1, you can use `array_search` to find the correct key for a given `gdat` value:

```
$array4 = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $key2 = array_search($value['gdat'], array_column($array2, 'gdat'));
    $array4[$key]['passers'] = $value['passers'] - $array2[$key2]['passers'];
    $array4[$key]['gdat'] = $value['gdat'];
}
```

For your sample data the results of both are the same:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 0
            [gdat] => 2019-02-06 
        ) 
    [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 96
            [gdat] => 2019-02-07 
        ) 
    [2] => Array 
        ( 
            [passers] => 1000
            [gdat] => 2019-02-08 
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/UXYt1)

Answer (score 0):

Put array one to `$array1` and array two in `$array2` and the result in `$result`

```
$result = [][];
foreach($array1 as $i => $a)
{
  // To avoid négative number we call absolute function
  $result[$i]['passers'] = abs($a['passers'] - $array2[$i]['passers']); 
  $result[$i]['gdat'] = $a['gdat'];
}
var_dump($result);
```